# Edit JavaScript function so it only applies to specified divs and not all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to carry out the action that I want, and it's working perfectly. I just don't know how to edit it so that it only applies to a certain class. Class would be better than IDs in this case, as some of the fields are dynamically generated and don't have specified IDs.

How can I edit this so that it only applies to a class name?

```js
function spanClicked() {
  var spanHtml = $(this).html();
  var editableText = $("<textarea />");
  editableText.val(spanHtml);
  $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
  editableText.focus();
  // setup the blur event for this new textarea
  editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
  var html = $(this).val();
  var viewableText = $("<span>");
  viewableText.html(html);
  $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
  // setup the click event for this new div
  viewableText.click(spanClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(spanClicked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Test</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Test2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Test3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `if($(this).hasClass('customClass'))`

Comment: Replace `$("div").click(divClicked)` with `$("div.whateverclass").click(divClicked)`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d1ozhmkp/2/

Comment: You should be able to get the target div from the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) then assign the target to divHtml `function divClicked(e) {
  var divHtml = e.target;`

Comment: Thank you Ab Sin - and as per my halfway dead brain right now, I need to apply it to a span as well. When I edit the fiddle to change to a span, it no longer works. How do I fix that please?

Comment: Hi Chemory. It's worth noting we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, religious material, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify classes to select, instead of just using `div`:

```js
function spanClicked() {
  var spanHtml = $(this).html();
  var editableText = $("<textarea />");
  editableText.val(spanHtml);
  $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
  editableText.focus();
  // setup the blur event for this new textarea
  editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
  var html = $(this).val();
  var viewableText = $("<span>", {
    class: 'editable'
  });
  viewableText.html(html);
  $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
  // setup the click event for this new div
  viewableText.click(spanClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".editable").click(spanClicked);
});
```

```css
.editable {
  color: red;
}

li {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Test</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="editable">Test2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Test3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes at all? I'd be interested to improve the answer

Comment: Thank you and I don't know why downvoted to be honest. Not my area of expertise or I wouldn't be asking :) 

I found it the easiest to understand - I just overlooked that I need it on a span, nto a div. It's inside a li. I have changed where it references div to span, everywhere in the snippet, but it isn't working. How else do i need to change it please?

Comment: Ah, ok; I'll edit the original question and update my answer, if it doesn't match what you have then please let me know

Comment: Thank you so much - been looking for someone to talk me through this for a few weeks. You wouldn't by any chance do skype coaching do you? I need someone to help me for an hour or two with a few questions I have. Look forward to seeing how ti works with span :) TIA :)

Comment: I've updated my answer; does that work for you? I don't currently do any skype coaching, but if you visit my stackoverflow profile you can find my contact details, I'd be happy to try and help further